# Sending nested json data with Python requests and in x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I cannot figure out how to do this. Basically one particular API is asking for

`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

yet they want the form data to be like this:

```
stockLevels=[
  {
    "SKU": "sample string 1",
    "LocationId": "de0f1890-0c49-4834-b8cd-8b766fba496a",
    "Level": 3
  },
  {
    "SKU": "sample string 1",
    "LocationId": "de0f1890-0c49-4834-b8cd-8b766fba496a",
    "Level": 3
  }
]
```

What I'm doing is this:

```
def change_stock_quantity(self, SKU, qty):
    # Note that this will change quantity of just one item
    # instead of two like in the example above
    payload = {
        'stockLevels':[{
          'SKU': SKU,
          'LocationId': self.ebay1_location_id,
          'Level': qty,
        }]
    }
    r = self.session.post(self.session_server + '//api/Stock/SetStockLevel',
                  data=payload)

    print r.request.body
    # stockLevels=SKU&stockLevels=LocationId&stockLevels=Level
    # this is not correct, it should be something like:
    # stockLevels:[{"SKU":"P01", "LocationId":"00000000", "Level":4}]

    print r
    # <Response [400]> (obivously)
```

Any ides on what do I do wrong?

Comment: Got a link to the API docs in question? EDIT: is it this one? https://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Stock-SetStockLevel If so the example is probably wrong, i.e they actually expect a JSON body. Try it raw,  e.g with CURL, to see what combinations work.

Comment: I actually solved it and will post a response below. They DO expect `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: cool, I did some research in parallel too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After mining this [GitHub repo's examples](https://github.com/LinnSystems/LinnworksNetSDK), their approach seems to be the following:

1. The body is, indeed, `x-www-form-urlencoded`
2. Complex parameters are JSON strings encoded for `x-www-form-urlencoded`

So looking at [their PHP example](https://github.com/LinnSystems/LinnworksNetSDK/blob/master/Linnworks/src/php/Stock.php#L63) for the [CreateVariationGroup](https://apps.linnworks.net/Api/Method/Stock-CreateVariationGroup) call, try this:

```
stockLevels=[
  {
    "SKU": "sample string 1",
    "LocationId": "de0f1890-0c49-4834-b8cd-8b766fba496a",
    "Level": 3
  },
  {
    "SKU": "sample string 1",
    "LocationId": "de0f1890-0c49-4834-b8cd-8b766fba496a",
    "Level": 3
  }
]

payload = {'stockLevels' : json.dumps(stockLevels)}

# send payload encoded with x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I found as well. What annoys me is that some of their API seems to be no longer working (e.g. https://apps.linnworks.net//Api/Method/Inventory-AddImageToItem) and I'm not sure how else can I actually upload an image through code. I'm very new to APIs in general, so maybe you could suggest me some standard way on finding available APIs of a given server?

Comment: I usually use the docs and example code - whether sample code, "native APIs" like the PHP + C# ones I linked to, or existing code that uses this API. For example, see this "code search" on GitHub for usages of the Linnworks API: https://github.com/search?q=linnworks&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: Ah, that's super useful, thanks! Unfortunately it seems like no one actually uses Python with Linnworks. While I can do some Java, I don't have any experience with C# or PHP. In either case, the reason why I'm bothering with this is because all my other apps that I want to connect it to are already built in Python and so I'll just continue using it.

Comment: Luckily enough, with Postman and their web app I can fetch all the APIs they send for the stuff I need - eg. image uploading is done through `api/Uploader/UploadFileFromUrl` and then it is attached to the item by `api/Inventory/UploadImagesToInventoryItem`